# In SQL, how can I display a column with either 'hours' or 'days' appended, depending on the difference in time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in my SQL query that returns a time duration:

```
ROUND(( xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5)|| ' days' AS "Average SOD Approval duration"
```

What I'd like to do is to display hours when the date-difference is less than 6 hours, and to display the days otherwise.

So if the difference in dates amounts to only 0.09 days, it should say  "2 hours" rather than 0.09 days.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm thinking to use a `CASE`, but not sure how to append it:

```
CASE expression

   WHEN  ROUND(( xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) < 0.25 THEN ??
   ...
   WHEN value_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple concatenation.

```
case when (( xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) < 0.25
then to_char((( xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5)) || ' hours'
etc
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
(CASE WHEN  ROUND(( xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) < 1
      THEN ROUND(24*(xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) || ' hours'
      ELSE ROUND(( xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) || ' days'
 END) AS "Average SOD Approval
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN ROUND((xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) IS NULL 
             THEN NULL 
             WHEN ROUND((xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) < 1
             THEN ROUND((xyz.DATE - abc.DATE) * 24, 5) || ' hours'
             ELSE ROUND((xyz.DATE - abc.DATE), 5) || ' days'
             END) AS "Average SOD Approval duration
FROM yourtablename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select (CASE
         WHEN (sysdate - trunc(sysdate)) * 86400 between 0 and 21600 /* if less than 6 hours */
          THEN
          ROUND(24 * (sysdate - trunc(sysdate)) ) || ' hours '
         WHEN (sysdate - trunc(sysdate)) * 86400 between 21601 and 43200 /* handle gab from 6hours to 12 hours as one day*/
          THEN '1 day '
         ELSE ROUND((sysdate - trunc(sysdate))) || ' days' /*handle more than 12 hours or nevative numbers*/
       END) 
  from dual;

enter code here
```

code explanation:

- for period between 0 and 6 hours then return rounded hours example 4h:30m=5h:00m
- for period less than half day then consider it and return as 1 day.
- for negative period or more than half day return round between two
  dates. (example 1 and half day returned as 2 days)
- replace sysdate with xyz.DATE and trunc(sysdate) with abc.DATE